# Drift and stuttering on prints

Tags: desktop-printer, y-axis, axis, monoprice-maker-ultimate, x-axis

I stopped using my Monoprice Maker Ultimate (re-branded Wanahao Duplicator 6) for a couple of weeks and am getting a seemingly random drift with all my prints now when re-attempting printing.

I also noticed a weird stutter when the extruder moves. It is particularly bad in one specific direction on the X-axis but is noticeable for all movement in the XY plane.

I have read online that this could be caused by voltage issues.

I have also read that it could be caused by over-tightened XY bearings but, given that it is happening in all directions, I am leaning more towards voltage issues.

Not sure if the drift and stuttering are related (I'd imagine they must be, but have no way of confirming). Would anyone be able to help provide troubleshooting steps for this as I am still very new to 3d printing?

I have provided a photo of what the drift looks like for [this test model](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2253091). I can provide more information if necessary. Thank you

[image: Drift image]

Comment: With the power off, can you feel "catching" while moving the extruder along the travel range?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding and apologies for my delay. I'm feeling some resistance in the X in one particular direction. Not so much along the Y axis. I wouldn't really call it catching though, just resistance. I've applied a couple drops of sewing machine oil to each of the rods and let the extruder run over them to try and spread across but that didn't seem to have much of an impact. Thank you again for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I shook off my laziness and disassembled the mounts holding the stepper motors and tightened the belts. After doing so the drift was resolved.